# How can i override function wp_insert_user() on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, function, overriding

I am making my first plugin to WordPress which needs insert the same user and password in a external database

So... I need get $userdata information at moment of registration.

How can I override this function: `wp_insert_user()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use the 'user_register' hook? Like this:

add_action( 'user_register', 'your_save_function', 10, 1 );

If you miss some userdata, check $_POST vars